# Fetch card information from HTML contentType from message action

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am developing a message action and trying to fetch the content of the card existing in the chat.

---

if, the content is normal text in the chat, then its not hard as seem below:

```
...
messagePayload: {
  ...
  body: { 
    contentType: 'text', 
    content: 'hello' 
  },
  ...
}
...
```

---

if, its an Adaptive / Hero card, I am fetching something like an HTML tag, as seen below:

```
...
messagePayload: {
  ...
  body: {
    contentType: 'html',
    content: '<attachment id="8a3e7358a8294a52ae95e8071c7e3ed3"></attachment>'
  },
  ...
}
...
```

Is there any way to get information from the above tag or any other way to fetch information?

Also, I achieved creating tasks using **create work item** from **Azure Board** message action. Looking for a similar thing working with my message action.

---

Please refer to the below attachment

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get **the card content** you have to do several steps:

1. Create Extension Command.
2. Select "**Allow users to trigger actions in external services while inside of Teams**".
   [image]
3. Select "**Fetch a dynamic set of parameters from your bot**".
   [image]
4. Handle **"composeExtension/fetchTask"** in your getInvokeHandler method ([Here's](https://github.com/skal1ozz/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/ff87057db2c411ed64c6c14de73ef9636e31c8cd/src/Bot.ts#L114) an example), or **handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction**.
5. Your **serialized card content** has to be in **event.value.messagePayload.attachments** if you are using **getInvokeHandler** and in **context._activity.value.messagePayload.attachments** if you are using **handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are developing Action based Messaging Extension. While initiating action through Bot sends invoke request to call OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync() you can call Get ChatMessage Graph API to [get chat message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request) and while submitting your HTML form/ card data it calls OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAsync() method in that request you will have your turnContext, you can parse the card data from turnContext.Action.Data, You can look at following sample code for more information How [action based messaging extension](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs) works in teams

Comment: I building a message action, and from that message-action want to pull all the information of the current card - the above image will help

Comment: Are you getting the fetch invoke, You will be having value with turnContext there you can check the data